# Open the same div on the next page using jQuery or JavaScript to remember

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Using the code below, I want to keep the same menu div opened in the next page. I probably need to use cookies, but I don't know how cookies work in JavaScript.

```
$(this)
    .css({backgroundColor:"#861b1b"})
    .next("div.menu_body")
    .slideToggle(300)
    .siblings("div.menu_body")
    .slideUp("slow");

$(this).siblings().css({backgroundColor:"#eee"});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided the browser allows it, cookies are accessed with:

```
document.cookie
```

There's also a good jQuery plugin for dealing with them: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Read the README file for examples and instructions.

A simple example to get you started.  First, when the user clicks on a menu:

```
$.cookie("current-menu",$(this).attr("id"));
```

Next, when the page loads:

```
if($.cookie("current-menu")) {
   OpenMenu($("#"+$.cookie("current-menu")));
}
```

OpenMenu should contain the code you posted above.  Make sure that your menu items have unique ids.

Comment: Yes, I saw this before and beacuse of this I said that i was searching for JQuery solutions also. But what I don't know is how to start, i mean which variable must be saved, or whatever, because there i don't use variables, I undersand Php but i'm in touble with JS and JQ..

Answer (score 1):

This should help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp